# Angular2 - How to configure the system-config.ts, if any new libraries are planned like angular2 -material2 package

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm little confusing on how this system-config.ts is configured and Now i'm trying to include material2 code into Angular quick start bundle but it didn't work.

In material2 github, it shows, need to add below configuration in the system-config.ts but not able to find a solution.
Below is the material2 dependency.

```
    // The core package is required as a peerDependency for other components.
'@angular2-material/core': {
  format: 'cjs',
  defaultExtension: 'js',
  main: 'core.js'
},
'@angular2-material/checkbox': {
  format: 'cjs',
  defaultExtension: 'js',
  main: 'checkbox.js'
},//
```

And in angular2 quick start, it looks like as below,

```
    (function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
  ];

  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
  if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Also other than this, Do I need to add anything to index.html page?
Older versions of angular2, I was able to configure it, but when the config is moved to new ts file I couldn't. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Do

```
var packages = {
    'app': {
        main: 'main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'rxjs': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    '@angular2-material/core': {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: 'core.js'
    },
    '@angular2-material/checkbox': {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: 'checkbox.js'
    }
};
```

---

You are confused maybe because of that `packageNames` but if you look below it there is a loop that's

just adding every packageNames member to `packeges` object and giving default values

`{ main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }`.